# TranslateAnimated ImageView not clickable after animation [Android]

Tags: android, animation, clickable

I have 2 `ImageView`s that I translate from the top of the screen to the bottom. these views are infalted from xml and the animation is added from java code. The animation works perfectly, but the `onClickListener` I added in java code doesn't seem to work. I used `fillAfter` attribute of the animation to make the iamges stay at their arrival after the translation, but THESE images aren't clickable anymore... However, their position before translation remains clickable...
I can't see the logic of this. Could anyone give me some piece of advice about that?

Comment: Ok, found my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125694/android-button-doesnt-respond-after-animation now I just need to set its params properly to get its position right...

Comment: However, this does not seem to be compatible with setFillAfter. I add to remove it to get it to work.

Comment: I had this problem, and I solved it after some research.
[Here you can find an answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333269/how-to-set-button-clickable-while-animating-on-android/18509197#18509197

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is because Animations affects only the drawing of widget. However, The real Location is not affected -It is still in the previous one-.

To overcome this problem, you need to update the layout parameters of the ImageView manually by installing an animation listener as follows:

```
Animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {

        }

        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
            //TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
            android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
            android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.topMargin = addLocationButton.getTop()-100;

            ImageView.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
        });
```

Comment: No good, because after the animation in onAnimationEnd, when the image get the position from "setLayoutParams(params);" then I see a flicker. I add that is difficult to set the topMargin from the percentage of the property toYDelta

Comment: To remove the flicker you can use            animation.reset();
<my view>.clearAnimation();