# android spinner nonclickable after animation

Tags: android, animation, spinner

I am animating a Relativelayout in my application that has a spinner in it.The layout animates just fine but the problem is I cannot select the Spinner after the animation.I am new to animation.Please Help me!!Below is the code:
MainActivity.java:

```
Animation slideup=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.slide_up);
               relativeLayout1.startAnimation(slideup);
               slideup.setFillAfter(true);
```

slide_up(anim):

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:toYDelta="-20%p"
        android:duration="2000"/>
</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because Animations affects only the drawing of widget. However, The real Location is not affected -It is still in the previous one-.

To overcome this problem, you need to update the layout parameters of the Spinner manually by installing an animation listener as follows:

```
Animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {

        }

        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
            //TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
            android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
            android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.topMargin = addLocationButton.getTop()-100;

            Spinner.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
        });
```

for more detail visit here : [TranslateAnimated ImageView not clickable after animation [Android]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397370/translateanimated-imageview-not-clickable-after-animation-android)