# Android java update the coordinates of image after animation happens

Tags: java, android

I have a animation where it moves to the right when I click on it. But, when I try to click on it again I have to click on it at same the spot it was at before.

How can I fix this and Where it will be able to click on it at it's new location?

Here's my code

```
   public void sideBar()
   {

       ImageView sidebar = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.sidebar);

       if(out == 0)
       {
       mSlideInRight = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_right);
       mSlideInRight.setFillAfter(true);
       sidebar.startAnimation(mSlideInRight);
       out= 1;
       }
       else if(out == 1)
       {
               mSlideInLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_left);
               sidebar.startAnimation(mSlideInLeft);
               out=0;
       }

   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the `ImageView` itself hasn't "actually" moved. You have to implement an animation listener and move the `ImageView` at the end of the animation.

Please refer this question: [Android Animation Flicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387711/android-animation-flicker)
and this: [Android Button Doesn't Respond After Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125694/android-button-doesnt-respond-after-animation?rq=1)